# getApplicationContext() cannot resolve method in fragment class-

Tags: android, android-fragments

this my code

```
package com.road.apoorv.road;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.content.Context; 
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {
View myView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_layout, container, false);

    GridView gridView = (GridView) myView.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));

    return myView;

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new     Intent(getApplicationContext(),FullImageActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("id", position);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}
}
```

I have tried getActivity().getApplicationContext() but it shows statement unreachable.

this is my first app so i am facing several problems.
thanks in advance

Comment: You should probably add the exact error message to the question.

Comment: please post the stack trace ...

Comment: Why don't you use `getActivity() ` or `getContext()`? You can read in the document,` getActivity()` or `getContext()` will get the `Activity` containing the `Fragment`.

Comment: Error:(41, 39) error: cannot find symbol method getApplicationContext()

Comment: @AbhishekSingharia check the edited answer..

Comment: @RoShanShan I have tried it too

Answer (score 1):

You should use `parent.getContext()`

Comment: it's because you are returning your view before setting onClickListener on gridView. Move your return statement at the end of the method.

Answer (score 0):

try :

Also add this code after u are setting the `setOnItemClickListener`

```
 gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent i = new  Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(),FullImageActivity.class);
       i.putExtra("id", position);
       startActivity(i);
    }
});


return myView;   //add it here
```

Comment: also use `getActivity().getBaseContext()`  inside `onItemClick`

Comment: clean build the apk ..use gradle sync